# A Markov normal algorithm for balanced parentheses check

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

The alphabet of the input string $P$ is defined as $$A = \{(,)\}.$$

Construct a Markov algorithm for checking whether the input string is parentheses-balanced.
The answer should be either $Y$ (yes) or $N$ (no).

It seems to me that I've found a solution to this problem. The schema goes as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
() \to \\
*( \to * \\
*) \to * \\
( \to * \\
) \to * \\
* \to N. \\
 \to Y.
\end{cases}
$$

In words:

1. The pairs of brackets $()$ are deleted.
2. If there are no brackets left, replace the empty word with $Y$ and stop.
   Otherwise, replace one bracket with $*$, delete the remaining ones, replace the $*$ with $N$ and stop.

Unfortunately, I cannot check myself because my book offers no solutions. Any hint would be appreciated!

Update: the rearranging of brackets is not needed!

Comment: This doesn't look quite right: you never delete any *'s! The Markov algorithm is supposed to return Y on "(())"  but yours returns N.